# linear queue by array implementation

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I made a linear queue data structure by array implementation.

In linear queue data structure elements are inserted from the front and deleted from the rear.
And in general, we show a message of overflow when the rear element is at the last index of the array, even if there are places to accommodate more elements in front.

For this, I came to a solution that every time deletion operation is performed I shift every element by one position through a loop operation.

But when I search the internet for the array implementation of linear queue, not even a single solution implement this approach. Even in geeksforgeeks they have not used this approach. As this approach is obvious to apply why haven't any of the standard solution applied it.

Does it increase the time complexity of the program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//the MAX is defined for array size
#define MAX 5
int q[MAX];
//here r indicates the index of last element in queue
int r=-1;
//function to insert element in queue
void insert();
//function to delete an element from queue
int delet();
//function to delete all the elements from the queue
void traverse();
int main()
{
    int choice;
    int value;
    printf("in 1\n");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("1. To insert an element to queue\n");
        printf("2. To delete an element from queue\n");
        printf("3. To delete all the elements from queue\n");
        printf("4. To Exit\n");
        printf("enter choice\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:insert();
                   break;
            case 2:value=delet();
                   value==-1?printf("queue is empty\n"):printf("the  
                   deleted element is %d\n",value);
                   break;
            case 3:traverse();
                   break;
            case 4:exit(0);
            default:printf("Enter a valid choice\n");
         }
    }
}
void insert()
{
    int item;
    //this is the condition for overflow
    if(r==MAX-1)
        printf("queue is full\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Enter item other than -1\n");
        scanf("%d",&item);
        r=r+1;
        q[r]=item;
    }
}
int delet()
{
    int temp,i;
    if(r==-1)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        temp = q[0];
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
            q[i]=q[i+1];
        r=r-1;
        return temp;
    }
}
void traverse()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=r;i++)
        printf("%d\n",q[i]);
}
```

Comment: Replace "linear queue" with "circular buffer" or "ring buffer". There are plenty implementations in various languages.

Comment: What @Groo says.  What you have designed is a circular queue with a load of avoidable overhead lumped in.

Comment: Maybe 'does it increasing the time complexity of the program?'.  Answer: sure.  O[n] 'cos copying the whole queue on insert/delete vs O[1] for a 'real' circular queue.

Comment: my question is that is there any problem in this approach as none of the standard solution implement this approach? And i am making a linear queue not circular, circular queue has a different approach @MichaelWalz

Comment: Trust groo, the ring buffer usually does (or is easily implemented to) exhibit the desired FIFO behaviour (what you describe as linear queue). Just with O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: @GauravSahu the issue with your method is that you have to move all the items in the list which is inefficient especially if the list is long, time complexity O(n). With the circular buffer approach you don't move the items, but you only move the head and the tail index and doing this is totally independant of the length of the list, time complexity O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that it takes a lot of processing to move everything up by one. In your `delet` function, you have this code:

```
{
    temp = q[0];
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        q[i]=q[i+1];
    r=r-1;
    return temp;
}
```

Now, imagine that you have one million items in the queue. When you delete an item from the queue, you have to move 999,999 items up by one place. That will take a very long time, in computer terms.

In terms of algorithmic complexity, removing from a circular queue is an O(1) operation: it takes the same amount of time regardless of how many items are in the queue. Your delete method is an O(n) operation: deleting an item takes time proportional to the number of items in the queue.

Functionally, there's nothing wrong with your implementation. But from a performance standpoint, your implementation will be much slower than the circular queue. This isn't something that you'll notice with a small test program, but when you start adding thousands or millions of things to the queue, your code would probably be unacceptably slow: thousands of times slower than the circular queue.

Comment: ..compounded if the queue has a lock around it.  The longer a lock is held, the greater the chance of expensive contention:(